# Discord.py user.block/user.send_friend_request: Error 403/Forbidden How do I give the bot permission to send friend requests and block users?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm currently trying to create a block user and send friend request command. However, I've hit a wall. It seems like the bot doesn't have permission or authorization to my account so it can't send friend requests or block users. How do I give it the permissions? Or maybe it isn't possible at all? Please let me know, I'd really appreciate it :>

My current code for the commands is below:

```
    @client.command()
    async def unfriend(ctx, *, user: discord.User):
        await user.remove_friend()
        await ctx.send('Friend has been removed')
    
    @client.command()
    async def sendrequest(ctx, *, user: discord.User):
        await user.send_friend_request()
        await ctx.author.send('Request sent')
@client.command()
async def block(ctx, *, user: discord.User):
    await user.block()
    await ctx.send(f'{member.mention} has been blocked by {ctx.author}')

@client.command()
async def unblock(ctx, *, user: discord.User):
    await user.unblock()
    await ctx.send(f"{member.mention} has been unblocked by {ctx.author}")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Discord does not allow bot users to add, block, or remove friends. You can only perform these actions through a normal Discord user, and if you were to do this through the program, that would be self botting, which is against Discord's Terms of Service.

Read about this send_friend_request() method here:

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=add%20friend#discord.User.send_friend_request

Discord's stance on self botting:

https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002192352-Automated-user-accounts-self-bots-

Comment: I see, do they at least allow bots to mute members? I can't find mute anywhere on the documentation

Comment: If you want to mute people in the chat, you have to get your bot to create a role, turn off the 'send messages' permission for that role in every channel for the guild, and assign it to the member that should be muted. If you want to voice mute members, then you can use the discord.Member.edit() method. More information on that here: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=edit#discord.Member.edit

Comment: Thanks for the info :> really appreciate it.