# Discord.py get user returns none

Tags: python, discord.py

I want ban any member from message with this code;

```py
elif "$ban" in message.content:
    msg = message.content
    msgsplit = msg.split() #banid[-1] gets last index of message array
    banidstr = msgsplit[-1]
    banid = int(banidstr)
    member = bot.get_user(int(banid))
    print(member)
```

It look like spaghetti but for testing. "print (member)" line returns none but "print (banid)" returns user ID. What can i do?

Comment: [maybe this helps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63258641/13891083)

Comment: Do you have `intents.members` enabled?

Comment: what is the "intents.members"? I tried now again and when i enter id manually, member correctly printed. But cant get member from message. I mean, "bot.get_user(int(banid))" not working. But "bot.get_user(12121121212121212)" working. This id was random.

Comment: I literally copy and pasted your code to test it, it works perfectly. Can you show the whole `on_message()` event? maybe the error is somewhere else.

Comment: https://imgur.com/D3j1fQl Whole event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes guys it worked;

```
async def ceza(ctx, *, message):
    cezaname=bot.get_user(int(message))
    print(cezaname)
```

This, printing username by id properly.

Answer (score 1):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65449226/12112111) post might help.

I also recommend you to use [`discord.ext.commands.Bot()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/neo-docs/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=discord%20ext%20commands%20bot#discord.ext.commands.Bot), where making commands is a lot easier:

```py
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?')

@bot.command()
async def echo(ctx, *, message):
    await ctx.send(message)

# Command will be invoked by user like '?echo this is the bot speaking'
# And the bot will then send 'this is the bot speaking'
```

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely easier. I'll use.